# adding the class id field to jsonschema for enums

Tags: jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

Is there a way to add the id property when generating jsonschema?
Using the jackson databind, I am:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
JsonSchemaGenerator jsg = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper, visitor);
JsonSchema jsonSchema = jsg.generateSchema(Status.class);
```

On the following enum:

```
public enum Status {
    ON,
    OFF;
}
```

It generates:

```
{
  "type" : "string",
  "enum" : [ "ON", "OFF" ]
}
```

However, if would like it to include the id:

```
{
  "id"   : "urn:jsonschema:com:example:enums:Status"
  "type" : "string",
  "enum" : [ "ON", "OFF" ]
}
```

Is this possible?